# WPF Class and corresponding Visual Style Inheritance

Tags: wpf, inheritance, styles, themes

I've looked but apparently can't get the syntax correct when correlating to classes and styles.  I have controls that have certain behavior.  Some I derive to add additional behavior.  Now, I want a style to correspond to each version.  In its simplest example, I will ignore those classes as I know style is specifically associated to visual and not function impact.  Some previous questions were close, but I am still missing something.

```
public class MyLabel : Label
{}

public class MyLabel2 : MyLabel
{}
```

So from the above, I should be able to have 3 styles in my resource dictionary.  One for the generic "Label", one for instances where I have a control that is derived from "MyLabel", and another for "MyLabel2".  The "local:" points to my class library per the "Theme" xaml declaration.

```
<Style x:Key="baseLabel" TargetType="Label">
   <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10" />
</Style>

<Style x:Key="styleMyLabel" TargetType="local:MyLabel"  BasedOn="{StaticResource baseLabel}" >
   <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
</Style>

<Style x:Key="styleMyLabel2" TargetType="{x:Type local:MyLabel2}" BasedOn="{StaticResource styleMyLabel}" >
   <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="22" />
</Style>
```

Again, for very simplistic purposes, just using a simple label for inheritance following purposes.  In my window xaml file.  Per the window xaml, the "src:" points to my class library, which is the same library as "local:" referenced in the theme (but I tried both ways... to have both instances refer to the xmlns:local in both, but it didn't appear to make a difference).

```
<src:MyLabel Content="Does Not Respect Style even though derived from MyLabel class" />
<src:MyLabel Content="This one works " Style="{DynamicResource styleMyLabel}" />

<src:MyLabel2 Content="This one doesnt work"/>
<src:MyLabel2 Content="This one works " Style="{DynamicResource styleMyLabel2}" />
```

I'm thinking I shouldn't have to explicitly identify the style if its derived from a class that has a style of the corresponding Target Type.  Hopefully its something stupid simple but I can't get my head wrapped around it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've stumbled into what APPEARS to be working as the answer, but don't understand why...  If I try to change the style for the MyLabel2 (which is the second derived instance)  from

```
<Style x:Key="styleMyLabel2" TargetType="{x:Type local:MyLabel2}" BasedOn="{StaticResource styleMyLabel}" >
   <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="22" />
</Style>
```

to (just removing the x:Key element)

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyLabel2}" BasedOn="{StaticResource styleMyLabel}" >
   <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="22" />
</Style>
```

the XAML works... WITHOUT having to explicitly associate the "Style" to be used.  It finds it based on the class association directly.

```
<src:MyLabel2 Content="Now Works as expected"/>
```

Now that it works, can someone maybe explain why the extra use of the x:Key reference kills it?  ie: if you have the x:key, its not implied by the class instance, but not having it, the direct class DOES find it automatically.

**EXPANDED FROM MY PLAYING AROUND WITH STYLES...**

So, here is some extras that I've found out.  A style can be defined more than once to the same TARGET TYPE... However, one can have an x:key reference, and another a BasedOn reference.  This APPEARS to be like overloading a function with same number, but different data type parameters.

In my problem, as soon as the "x:Key" reference was added to the style, any direct class instances of the "TargetType" were NOT automatically linked up to the proper style, almost like  the style declaration with the "x:key" REQUIRES any instances of a class to explicitly add the style context within the xaml of the control.  So now, how to have it BOTH ways.  I created a SECOND style with the TargetType as the baseclass, but had ITs BasedOn pointing to the x:key referenced one.  This way, I get the default customization of the style, yet can STILL assign it to the baseclass and the derived class as well, so all 3 versions of a control can be automatically synchronized with the corresponding Style without EXPLICIT referencing.

```
<Style TargetType="Label" x:Key="wpfBaseLabel">
   <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11" />
</Style>

<Style TargetType="Label" BasedOn="{StaticResource wpfBaseLabel}" />

<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyLabel}" BasedOn="{StaticResource wpfBaseLabel}">
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
</Style>
```

So, now, within the final XAML, I can have all 3 "classes" used with or without explicit style association.