# Updating MainWindow Property from separate MVVM Module

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am looking to implement a "JQuery" style spinner in a WPF application. As this spinner will be triggered from some separate PRISM modules and I want the spinner to cover the whole application window I need to get access to a property in the MainWindow.

I have a property in the MainWindow but I am not able to see it from the other modules.

I have tried Application.Current.MainWindow but no luck.

I have also tried using the Application.Current.Properties[] but I do not know how to trigger a OnPropertyChanged event.

Can someone point me in the right direction please.

Update:
Here are some screenshots and a better description of what I want to do.

Ok, here is an example of my issue. I have an application that contains the following:

- WPFApp
- WPFApp.Module1
- WPFApp.Module2
- WPFApp.Module3
- WPFApp.Module4

The WPFApp MainWindow contains 2 regions, a Menu region (on the left hand side) and a Content region.
Each module contains 2 views:

- A menu view, which is loaded into the MainWindow Menu region
- A content view, which is loaded into the MainWindow Content region

In each of the Module content views I want to perform a task that will take a few seconds and while the task is being performed I want to show a “Ajax Style” spinner that will cover the whole application window.
To have used the spinner class detailed here: [WPF Spinner via MVVM & Attached Properties](http://deanchalk.com/2010/11/13/wpf-loading-spinner-via-mvvm-and-attached-properties/)
I have been able to use this by adding the AsyncNotifier.Trigger (detailed in the link above) to each of the modules content view, see below.

[image]
[image]

My problem is:
If I want the spinner to cover the whole application window then I need to add the AsyncNotifier.Trigger to the MainWindow. I also need to expose a property from the MainWindow responsible for showing the spinner and be able to access this from each of the modules.
Any ideas on how to do this?

Update:

Ok, I think I might be getting a bit further but still a little bit stuck on how everything fits together.

I have created my Interface and put it into my Infrastructure module so every other module can access it.

I am using the following piece of code to load my modules from my AggregateModuleCatalog class.

```
/// <summary>
/// this.Catalogs is a readonly collection of IModuleCatalog
/// Initializes the catalog, which may load and validate the modules.
/// </summary>
public void Initialize()
{
    foreach (var catalog in this.Catalogs)
    {
        catalog.Initialize();
    }
}
```

My problem is that I am unsure of where I should put the SpinnerViewModel? Should it be in my Main project.

Also, where should I pass in the singleton using Constructor injection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would look at implementing the mediator pattern here. This is already present in Prism in the form of the `EventAggregator`

Basically, it sounds like you want to publish control messages of a certain type to any subscribers - in this case you have:

- Subscribers

  - MainWindow
- Publishers

  - Module 1
  - Module 2
  - Module 3

The modules should publish a message to signal that they want to 'busy' the `MainWindow` whilst work is being done/module is being loaded etc

The key thing is that they should not be aware of the `MainWindow` in any way. This keeps the solution decoupled, MVVM friendly, reusable and easily maintained. This method uses dependency injection, which is usually a good idea :)

In order for this to work, the modules need to take a dependency on the `EventAggregator` service (there is an `IEventAggregator` interface in PRISM which is your service interface) and should then publish messages to it

First you need an event which will serve as the message class. Obviously this needs to be visible from both the publisher and subscriber, so may need to sit in an external reference. This needs to inherit from `CompositeWpfEvent` and you should provide a generic argument for the message payload.

```
public class BusyUserInterfaceEvent : CompositeWpfEvent<bool>
{
}
```

(I suppose you could just directly use `CompositeWpfEvent<bool>` for this which may work equally as well but is not specific enough if you decide to include more event types which use bool as payloads)

Then you need to publish events of the above type from your module

```
public class Module1
{
    private IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;

    public Module1(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
    }

    public DoSomeWork()
    {
        // Busy the UI by publishing the above event
        _eventAggregator.GetEvent<BusyUserInterfaceEvent>().Publish(true);
    }

    public FinishDoingSomeWork() 
    {
        // Unbusy the UI by publishing the above event with 'false'
        _eventAggregator.GetEvent<BusyUserInterfaceEvent>().Publish(false);
    }
}
```

The `MainWindow` should also take a dependency on the `EventAggregator` service and should subscribe to any messages of a certain type. If work is to be done on the UI thread (as it is in this case) you should subscribe using `ThreadOption.UIThread`

```
public class MainWindow
{
    private IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;

    public MainWindow(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;

        // Subscribe to any messages of the defined type on the UI thread
        // The BusyUserInterface method will handle the event
        _eventAggregator.GetEvent<BusyUserInterfaceEvent>().Subscribe(BusyUserInterface, ThreadOption.UIThread);
    }

    public BusyUserInterface(bool busy)
    {
        // Toggle the UI - pseudocode here!
        TickerActive = busy;
    }
}
```

Whilst I have used this pattern in a couple of frameworks successfully before, I admit that I haven't used PRISM so the above code might not be quite right, however, the docs seem concise:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122.aspx

Using this pattern decouples any components, so it's easy to stop the `MainWindow` from subscribing to the events and to move the subscriber to a parent component if needs be without touching the implementation of the publishers.

This means you could swap the `MainWindow` for a completely different window and load your modules in during some part of your application lifecycle, and as long as it was subscribing to these event types it would still busy/unbusy based on the message publishing from the modules. It's a very flexible solution.

PRISMs implementation also provides subscription filtering so you can selectively listen for events.

Additionally, since you are aggregating events there's a lot you can do with this to allow inter-module communication. The only challenge you have is making sure everyone is aware of the message types, which is why an external dependency may be needed to hold the message types

Comment: I use this pattern all over the place for spinner UI elements, and this is very similar to the code I use. However, shouldn't the EventAggregator take a more global scope?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by global scope, to me, busying an element at the top of the control tree from a sub element is decoupled inter-component communication, which is what the event aggregator does. I wouldn't consider this too limited a scope - since you are creating your own event types you can determine at which level the messages interact with components.

Comment: @Charleh, worked like a charm. Thanks man really appreciate it.

Comment: @Charleh I think what I didn't see initially is that you've got an IoC pattern going on that I didn't think to use in my stuff. I just declared (in Visual Basic) a `Module` with a `Shared` IEventAggregator and I use that app-wide. Your approach is more flexible; I'm happy to be wrong about this!

Answer (score 2):

Am I missing something? Should this be as easy as this?

**App.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class App
{
   public static Window MainWindow {get;set;}
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public MainWindow()
{
    App.MainWindow = this;
    InitializeComponent();
}
public void Spinner(bool show)
{
    // Your code here
}
```

Now in MVVM, the idea would be the same, just don't do it in code behind. You could create a singleton (Singleton has a static instance) for the spinner to bind to and then any module can mess with the singleton property.

If you like Dependency Injection, create an interface, create an object that implements that interface, have the Spinner bind to that object. Then inject that object as the interface into the modules when they are loaded.

Here is a singleton ViewModel that implements an interface. Your Prism projects need to know only about the interface. But your code that loads your Prism modules should know about both the interface and the singleton. Then when the Prism Modules are loaded, the singleton would be passed in (feel free to use whichever injection method is easiest: constructor injection, method injection, or property injection).

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace ExampleCode
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interface for managing a spinner
    /// </summary>
    public interface IManageASpinner
    {
        bool IsVisible {get;set;}
        // Add any other properties or methods you might need.
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// A singleton spinner ViewModel for the main window spiner
    /// </summary>
    public class SpinnerViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, IManageASpinner
    {        #region Singleton and Constructor
        /// <summary>
        /// Singleton instance
        /// </summary>
        public static SpinnerViewModel Instance
        {
            get { return _Instance ?? (_Instance = new SpinnerViewModel()); }
        } private static SpinnerViewModel _Instance;

        /// <summary>
        /// Private constructor to prevent multiple instances
        /// </summary>
        private SpinnerViewModel()
        {
        }
        #endregion

        #region Properties
        /// <summary>
        /// Is the spinner visible or not? 
        /// Xaml Binding: {Binding Source={x:Static svm:SpinnerViewModel.Instance}, Path=IsVisible}
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsVisible
        {
            get { return _IsVisible; }
            set
            {
                _IsVisible = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsVisible");
            }
        } private bool _IsVisible;

        // Add any other properties you might want to include
        // such as IsSpinning, etc..

        #endregion

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged implementation
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Hope you can connect the dots from here.

**Added Feb 12**

Maybe use Method injection? I am not sure you can though.Can you edit the IModuleCatalog interface or the Catalog class? If not, skip this and go to the next idea.

```
foreach (var catalog in this.Catalogs)
{
    catalog.Initialize(SpinnerViewModel.Instance);
}
```

Maybe your Catalogs should implement a second interface and use property injection instead of constructor injection.

```
public interface IHaveASpinner
{
   public IManageASpinner Spinner {get;set;}
}
```

Now, have all your catalogs that implement IModuleCatalog also implement IHaveASpinner.

Then have your code do this:

```
foreach (var catalog in this.Catalogs)
{
    catalog.Initialize();
    var needSpinner = catalog as IHaveASpinner;
    if (needSpinner != null)
    {
        needSpinner.Spinner = SpinnerViewModel.Instance;
    }
}
```

**Where I should put the SpinnerViewModel?**

I would suggest your main project. It depends on your design. Do all the modules already reference your main project? If so, then put it in your main project. If not, then perhaps there is a project the main project and all the modules already reference? You could even create a separate project/dll specific for your spinner, but only if you have to as that might be overboard unless you have a strict design with rules for what can reference what.

Comment: in MVVM can you give me an example of how I could use Dependency Injection to solve this.

Comment: Well, I wrote you an example interface and singleton ViewModel that implements the interface. See the comments in the ViewModel for info on binding to a Singleton's property.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need a VM just for the spinner. What I do is have the spinner itself (animation, icon, whatever) in my main window's view, and have the main window VM implement the following interface:

```
public interface IApplicationBusyIndicator
{
    bool IsBusy { get; set; }
}
```

Using your favourite IoC container (I use Castle), I just inject IApplicationBusyIndicator into other VMs. Whenever one of these starts some long-running task it just sets IsBusy to true (then back to false when it's finished). The busy indicator in the main window view has its Visibility property bound to the main window VMs `IsBusy` property (using a boolean-to-visibility converter of course).

If, in your scenario, there is some architectural constraint preventing VMs in other modules from being injected with an instance of the main window VM, then you could use Prism's event aggregator to publish a message to say "application busy", and have the main window VM subscribe to the event, and show the busy indicator.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to create more of some "visual" style / interface of a spinner, I suggest looking into creating your own subclass spinner (if you need special functionality behind it), and then create your own customized style for its look / behavior.  Then when you put the spinner on the forms, just use a spinner of the class/style you designate and they should function for you well.

[Here is one of my own learning about styles, but simple label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723741/wpf-class-and-corresponding-visual-style-inheritance)

[Another link where I helped someone walking through creating their own custom class/style which MIGHT be what you are trying to globally implement.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13274956/wpf-custom-button-best-approach/13276319#13276319)

[And a link to template / style defaults to learn from](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: thanks for that. I have my spinner class and style already setup and I have it placed on my Main window and I have it bound to a property in the MainWindow ViewModel but I am looking to be able to update this property from a different Module.

Comment: let me explain a bit better. 
The MainWindow contains 2 regions, a menu and content.
It is also where the spinner will be loaded from so that the whole application is covered by the spinner.
Each module contains a view for the menu region as well as a view for the content region.
I want the spinner to be triggered by an action in the content view of a module.
The problem is I do not know how to setup a property in the MainWindow that I can access from each of the module content viewmodels to trigger the spinner to load.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Nollaig, it might help if you can do a print-screen / paste a sample (even if you shrink it up some) and add to your post to view to better clarify... then add your comment/clarification back in your original post... in the mean-time, I'll try to ponder what you are looking for.