# Issue with WPF styles

Tags: wpf, xaml

I wonder if someone can help, I am designing a custom WPF window for an application i am working on and I have an issue with the Min, Max and Close buttons. I have designed a `ControlTemplate` for the 3 buttons and they are in a `StackPanel` with `Vertical` orientation.  In my base style I have the following

```
<Style x:Key="BaseWindowButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value={Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type FrameworkElement}}, Path=(TextElement.Foreground)}" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    ...
</Style>
```

Have also tried setting the Foreground to a specific color such as `#FF000000` and nothing displays

I have a style that inherits this style for the buttons but does not change the foreground or background.

My problem is that the button content does not display, the button displays and the `IsMouseOver` trigger fires which changes the background but the textual content never displays.

The Min button style is

```
<Button x:Name="PART_Min">
    <Path Fill="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}"
          Data="F1M0,6L0,9 9,9 9,6 0,6z"
          SnapsToDevicePixels=True" />
</Button>
```

I am at a loss as to why the content does not display so would appreciate your thoughts.

The Visual Tree is below, I have examined this and identified the Foreground values

```
Window (Foreground: #FF000000)
  Grid
    AdornerDecorator
      Grid
        ContentControl (Foreground: #FF000000)
          StackPanel
            Button (Foreground: #FF000000)
              Grid
                ContentControl (Foreground: #FF000000)
```

But like I said above I have removed the binding and specified a physical value and still do not get the content displaying

Comment: What value is the binding to `TextElement.Foreground` resolving to?

Comment: I am new to WPF so that is where my understanding is limited but the relative source binding will be to the base type of the Button whose type is FrameworkElement

Comment: `{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type FrameworkElement}}` will use the a `FrameworkElement` from higher in the element tree, _not_ the inheritance tree. This is likely to the be the Button's parent element. Use Visual Studio's 'Live Visual Tree' to find the what the binding values are.

Comment: Instead of `<Setter Property="Foreground" Value={Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type FrameworkElement}}, Path=(TextElement.Foreground)}" />` use a named `TextBlock` or `Label`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `ContentPresenter` instead of `ContentControl` in your button's template. (You should include the button's control template in a question like this... it's potentially highly relevant.)

Comment: This was the problem, in the buttons `ControlTemplate` I had defined a custom `ContentControl` to add some extra properties and I had not defined a `Style` for the custom `ContentControl` therefore as you alluded to in you answer there was no `ContentPresenter`, I had been looking at it for so long I was unable to see the wood for the trees

Answer (score 1):

As I too was a beginner with WPF, and trying to understand things was a bit of a learning curve, I would like to offer a few previous links posted out here.

First a simple style for [creating simple label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723741/wpf-class-and-corresponding-visual-style-inheritance) and having all labels as a default take on this format without explicit style assignments.

Another sample showing [creation of a custom button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13274956/wpf-custom-button-best-approach/13276319#13276319).  This is where I went step by step to create a custom class and apply a style to it to show/hide image on a button.

Maybe the button link and style declaration will help you find your button coloring issues too.